# Alternative to Oracle Enterprise user security in SQL Server or other databases

Tags: sql-server, oracle, security

Is there an alternative to Oracle Enterprise User Security in SQL Server and other databases ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, SQL Server knows nothing about Oracle Enterprise User Security.

SQL Server supports tow types of logins:

1. The classic login/password type of security,
2. 'Windows Trusted' security, which is similar to 'Externally Identified' security in Oracle, i.e. it trusts that windows has verified your identity and uses whatever windows thinks you ar (i.e. your window login)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have been through the above two authentication types. Was wondering if SQL Server supports anything as enterprise user security. But as you pointed out, there seems to be only these two ways to connect to SQL Server.

Comment: No. There's no reason to as everyone on windows uses Active Directory.

Comment: Yes, I understand. Was only curious to learn different ways of connecting the SQL Server performing a single point to manage identities. What if the user in Active Directory not a windows user ? Then in this case how will SQL Server trust this user for connecting and accessing database ?

Comment: _What if the user in Active Directory not a windows user_ - I'm not sure I understand. If you're using some kind of client app in a windows enterprise environment, you're in active directory. Active Directory _is_ enterprise security on windows